# Insert value in textboxes in table rows using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to insert values in table containing textboxes. My result is fetched using Dictionary and returning result through json. The value is successfully fetched but it is not getting inserted inside textboxes. Below is my code.

**file.cshtml**

```
<div><input type="text" class="txtbox" id=@Guid.NewGuid().ToString() /></div>


$(document).ready(function () {

        var full_url = document.URL;
        var url_array = full_url.split('/') // Split the string into an array with / as separator
        var last_segment = url_array[url_array.length - 1];  // Get the last part of the array (-1)
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("PageLoad", "Instructor")',
            data: { id: last_segment },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val) {
                    $.each(val, function(key,val)
                    {
                         $.each(val, function (key, val) {
                             $("#tbl tr.item").each(function () {
                                 //$(this).find("input.txtbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                                 $(this).find("input.txtbox").value = val.Result; //Here i'm trying to set value 
                                alert(val.Result);
                                return false;
                            });

                        });
                    });
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: You need to do : `$(this).find("input.txtbox").val(val.Result);`

Comment: Yes JazaKallah and Thank you @HamzaAbdaoui :)

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this

```
 $(this).find("input.txtbox").val( val.Result);
```

Set the value attribute:

```
$(selector).val(value)
```

for reference  check [api.jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

You are using $.each incorrectly $.each is receiving :-

1- **array**
  Type: Array
  **The array to iterate over.**

2- **callback**
  Type: Function( Integer **indexInArray**, Object **value** )

**The function that will be executed on every object.**

In Each Iteration the value passed to the function is a record from your dictionary so each record will have key and value you must Iterate over each value again.

you are using 3 variables with the same name and this will be very confusing.

You should insert your values like this:-

```
$(this).find("input.txtbox").val(val.Result);
```

I don't exactly understand why you return !!

Comment: Well i forgot to mention in my question that i used dictionary inside dictionary. That is why i had to loop three time. I wanted to execute inner loop once only, that's why i used return false.